# How to open unc path in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have an application using unc path to open some files. The unc location is stored in the database. Now we want to create an application in iOS and we have the problem the user can be outside the network. The company has a vpn enviroment.

My question is, how we can open the files or if possible send the unc to the ios application and open this files using the vpn connection.

Comment: So that others don't have to Google it, by "unc" the OP probably means [Uniform Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any straightforward way to do this. UNC paths reference a CIFS network file share, and iOS does not natively support networked file shares of any variety.

You may be able to accomplish this by embedding a library that can access CIFS file shares (such as Samba), but that's going to be an extraordinarily complex and painful process. A better solution will be to store the files in a storage system that is not bound to CIFS.

Comment: I was afraid to hear that. Thanks for your help, maybe we can build a little web service to obtain the documents.